# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre montón y montaña?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras

Cuando se usa para describir una cantidad grande, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre montón y montaña? Al principio, pensaba que se usa `montón` con sustantivos masculinos y `montaña` con sustantivos femeninos, pero acabo de escuchar "un montón de cosas" y entonces ahora no estoy seguro de nada.

Comment: James: ¿qué investigación realizaste al respecto? Nótese que ambas palabras están en el diccionario, por lo que mostrar la comparación de definiciones es algo deseable a la hora de plantear la pregunta.

Comment: el diccionario no me describió la diferencia las palabras como sentido figurado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"montón" sería equivalente a "a lot of". Puede utilizarse indistintamente con sustantivos masculinos o femeninos.

"montaña" no es tan usual. En realidad, puede utilizarse en un sentido figurado (*a heap of, a pile of*) o real, tanto con sustantivos masculinos como femeninos. También indica una gran cantidad, normalmente de cosas que se pueden apilar o imaginarse apiladas, por ejemplo: *una montaña de billetes* (en este caso, el sentido es real) / *una montaña de problemas* (sentido figurado: *one on top of another*).

Nota: No decimos en español "cantidad larga" sino "gran cantidad" (o "cantidad grande"). En realidad, "large" en inglés nunca es "largo" en español (equivalente a "long" en inglés).

Answer (score 0):

Montón es de una gran cantidad de algo (A lot), Y montaña es un relieve de la tierra, (Mountain).

Pero si te refieres a las dos de manera de cantidad, Montón y montaña serian similares.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que "montaña" se puede usar también en sentido figurado, con un sentido similar a "montón", por lo que cabría esperar que la respuesta fuera un poco más detallada con respecto a lo que indica quien pregunta.

Comment: Cierto Alejandro, pero creo que la pregunta es acerca del sentido figurado de ambos. Puedes elaborar más?

Comment: Perdón, Es cierto, La verdad no lo habia entendido, Voy a editar el post.